# Delete a single character from the end of a range of text

Tags: vba, ms-word, range

I am trying to use VBA code to delete the last character (",") off of a specific range.
It gives me a compile error saying "Expected: =" when I enter the code I have.

Here is my line of code that is giving me problems.

```
doc.Bookmarks("F1").Range.Delete(wdCharacter,-1)
```

Comment: Can you show the simplest example that exhibits this problem - we don't know how all the elements in your expression are defined... At first sight it looks like you need to assign the return value to a variable? It would be good if you gave all the info needed to be able to reproduce the error. Pasting your code into a VBA sub doesn't meet that standard (yet). Can you edit in some additional clarification?

Answer (score 1):

The following code appears to do what you want:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
  Dim r
  If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("mark1") Then
    r = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("mark1").Range.End
    ActiveDocument.Range(r - 1, r).Delete
  End If
End Sub
```

Explanation:

1. Always declare your variables; `Option Explicit` will complain if you forget / misspell
2. Check the bookmark exists
3. Find the position of the last character of the bookmark
4. Delete the range of characters starting one from the end

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are calling the method Delete as a *function* by using **parenthesis**. Functions have return values that have to be stored somewhere. Hence the quite literal error message "Expected: =".
Try calling it as *procedure* (i.e. not expecting a return value) by removing the **parenthesis**:

```
doc.Bookmarks("F1").Range.Delete wdCharacter,-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way of deleting last character of your bookmark:

```
doc.Range(doc.Bookmarks("F1").End - 1, _
            doc.Bookmarks("f1").End).Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to just delete the last character in a line of code. This worked for me:

```
Selection.Characters.Last.Delete unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
```

This deletes the last character of the selection.